# Sending Outlook emails to a distribution list with sendmailR

Tags: r, outlook

I am looking to send an email to a distribution list I have set up in Outlook through the sendmailR package. Sending to one email is simple:

```
from <- "me@me.com"
to <- "you@you.com"
```

I understand how to send it to more than one person

```
to <- c("you@me.com","joe@me.com")
```

But sending it to a distribution list already set up in Outlook is not working. I'm hoping I don't have to copy all the emails into R... there are hundreds.

Thanks

Comment: I am tagging this with the Outlook tag as I think the issue is likely more to do with Outlook than with R. It sounds like the Outlook "list" is not an email address like, say, a Google Group or other reflector.

Comment: Good call, thank you.

Comment: An idea, which may not work for you: can you somehow "read in" the list item from a contact (maybe save it in some format and then read it into your R code)? So you can script the "importing" process.

Comment: Definitely going to try that if this doesn't work out. Although it being outlook, I'm skeptical if there is a text format of all my contacts somewhere. I will certainly look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like exporting the distribution list from Outlook as a text file and then reading it into R is the easiest way to do as I found. If you have groups within groups you'll need to export them separately. Not the fastest way of doing it, but once it's done, it works well.